# Is there something like Shared Objects for Windows Forms applications?

Tags: windows, forms, object, shared

I need to have some data which can be updated and be available among a number of Win form applications. (Just like Shared Objects in Flex/Flash).
Any client can update the piece of data and this update should reach every other client. 
Is there something in Windows Form Apps that could match my requirments?

Comment: What kind of updates? Are you not using any data storage?

Comment: this is commonly called a database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store the central data to be shared in a database, each application could ping the database to get the updated data. If you dont want to use the database, you could binary serialize the object and pass it to other applications, you could make applications talk to each other by using sockets etc.